# How to change device label in Electrum?

Tags: electrum, hardware-wallet

Say one has a multi-sig Electrum wallet created using Electrum and two Trezor devices… can one change Trezor labels to COLDCARD labels without connecting COLDCARD devices (referring to device labels, see example below)?

[image: Electrum]